# Why can't matplotlib draw in the window while the main thread is sleeping?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to do something like below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

plt.ion()
plt.show()
for i in range(10):
  plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3]) # dummy data
  sleep(2)
  plt.cla()
  sleep(2)
```

But this does not work. The window appears, but nothing is drawn in it, and all buttons are dead too.

So I experimented a bit. If I paste the following into a Python shell, it shows the graph as expected.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

plt.ion()
plt.show()
plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
#sleep(60)
```

But if I comment out the last line, the window appears, but empty. I don't see why it behaves like that, can someone explain?

Comment: what are you expecting your first piece of code to do?

Comment: I've had some issues with different interactive shells and backends behaving differently. I've had the best luck with iPython. Are you using an iPython shell?

Comment: @ThePredator: I expect the code to show an empty window for two seconds, then a window with a line for two seconds, then over again. In my original project I want it to clear the window, then update with new data, every x seconds. But I used a simpler piece of code, which illustrates behavior that I can't explain.

Comment: @farenorth: The examples shown behaves the same with iPython and the ordinary Python shell. One important difference with iPython is, that it has interactive mode on by default, which makes the ion() superfluous.

Comment: Because you only have one thread which is dealing with both your code and the gui main loop.  If the thread is sleeping, nothing happens.  Use `plt.pause()`

Comment: and when you use ipython the gui main loop is hooked into the repl main loop so it works

Comment: @tcaswell: Hmmm... I can sort of understand what you are telling me, but this is far from simple. If there is only one thread, then how come the drawing is happening  when... the REPL is waiting for the next command, besides when calling pause.

Comment: Look at the ipython repl/main loop integration code.  And no, it is not simple.

Comment: Do you mean looking at the source code? That's beyond my skills.